# How to add a name to field of a form/how to refer to id [.module Drupal]?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, drupal

I have a form generated by Drupal of id #x with few fields with names: "sname", "tag", "dsr", and I am changing some things in my .module file this way, using its names:

```
  if($form['#id'] == 'x') {
    $form['sname']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = '- Name of show -';
    $form['tag']['#options']['All'] = '- Type of offer -';
    $form['dsr']['#options']['All'] = '- All shops -';   
  }
```

The problem is that one field has no name, it has only id (#z) and class (.zz). How can I refer to it using its id or how can I add a name to that field?

Comment: Can you post a dump of the $form so we can see which key holds this element.